# How to retrieve data from my old Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id

I want to retrieve data from my old Apple ID. I have signed in my iPhone with my old Apple ID, but iTunes displays an error:

> "We cannot complete your iTunes store request. An unknown error occured (0x800B0101)"
>
> "There was a error in the itunes store. Please try again later"

I have tried this many times only to get the same results.

Answer (score -1):

First try changing your [iTunes account password via your computer](https://iforgot.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSiForgot.woa/wa/iforgot).

Then try logging in again.

If that doesn't work, then try changing the date on your phone temporarily. Go to Settings > General > Date and Time > Set Automatically > Off. Set the date one year ahead. Then try and see if it accepts your password.

If you still can't sign in, contact Apple Store Customer Service at 1-800-676-2775.